# Гардина/Гардины

Tags: склонение, общие-вопросы

Вопрос

Гардина, это целый, неделимый предмет, либо, состоящий из двух и более частей?

К примеру "... около плавно вальсирующей в одиночестве гардины"

Подразумевается, что есть эта самая гардина (штора), так будет ли правильным, если станет написанным

"...около плавно вальсирующих в одиночестве гардин (т.н. шторин)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: "... около плавно вальсирующей в одиночестве гардины"

ИЗ СЛОВАРЯ

ГАРДИНА, -ы; ж. [нем. Gardine].Занавеска, закрывающая всё окно.

ШТОРА, -ы; ж. [франц. store]Оконная занавеска, отодвигаемая в сторону и поднимаемая кверху (обычно при помощи шнура). Поднять, опустить штору (шторы). Задёрнуть шторы.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Слова "штора, гардина" имеют две формы числа, но из текстов мы видим  на окнах гардину или штору (ед.ч.), например:

"Сейчас же задымились обои, загорелась сорванная гардина на полу..." (М. Булгаков). "Для спальни подойдут две-три прозрачные драпировки близких оттенков  плюс плотная гардина из натурального шелка". "Но штора по-прежнему висела не шевелясь"  (В. Катаев). "Представил, что сейчас отдернется штора, появится лицо судьи, темный силуэт, белые руки"(З. Прилепин).

Вероятно, мн. число используется в выражениях "купить гардины, шторы на окна", опустить шторы на окнах.